# Auto-fit row data but do not auto-fit column header

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-formula

I am building a table in a vba script using

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:A" & numRows & ":Z1:Z" & numRows), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"`

and it auto fits the columns.

Is there away to have the columns auto fit only to the row data and not the columns, so potentially the columns headers could be cut off?

Comment: You probably can't affect the way that method autofits. However, immediately afterward you could do `Range("A2:A" & numRows & ":Z2:Z" & numRows).Columns.Autofit` which will autofit only based on the table entries (notice how I start at row 2 to cut off the headers).

Comment: Try using ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns.AutoFit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns.AutoFit worked. Credit to @CS